# Sort an array according to the value in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Here is my array . I want to sort the array according the value of each key
Input array:-

```
Array
(
    [location_classroom] => 209
    [location_daily_pe] => 1
    [location_hallways] => 3
    [location_playground] => 93
    [location_shade_area] => 26
    [location_specialist] => 8
    [location_toilet] => 3
    [location_others] => 27
    [location_others_info] => 0
)
```

Output array:-

```
Array
(
    [location_others_info] => 0
    [location_daily_pe] => 1
    [location_hallways] => 3
    [location_toilet] => 3
    [location_specialist] => 8
    [location_shade_area] => 26
    [location_playground] => 93
    [location_classroom] => 209
    [location_others] => 27

)
```

Comment: Try reading this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: `asort` should do exactly that for you.  http://us2.php.net/asort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed you should use `asort()`:

```
$arr = [
    'location_classroom' => 209,
    'location_daily_pe' => 1,
    'location_hallways' => 3,
    'location_playground' => 93,
    'location_shade_area' => 26,
    'location_specialist' => 8,
    'location_toilet' => 3,
    'location_others' => 27,
    'location_others_info' => 0
];

asort($arr);
# but you can't print the output of the sorting - it'll give you nothing meaningful (boolean)
# you should print the sorted array itself
print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 Array
(
    [location_others_info] => 0
    [location_daily_pe] => 1
    [location_toilet] => 3
    [location_hallways] => 3
    [location_specialist] => 8
    [location_shade_area] => 26
    [location_others] => 27
    [location_playground] => 93
    [location_classroom] => 209
)
```

Comment: @AwladLiton that's the order the OP was looking for (see details in the question above)

Comment: I have edited your output array in your answer. this output was expected by OP :)

Comment: @AwladLiton oh right :) I guess I pasted the wrong window, thanks man!